# Connect to FTP using FTPS TLS

Tags: java, ftps

Error when trying to connect to a FTP server ("TLS",implicit) using FTP

```
FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient("TLS");
ftps.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
int reply;
    try {
        ftps.connect("server");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ftpimport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
reply = ftps.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    try {
        ftps.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ftpimport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTPs Server");
}
ftps.execPBSZ(0); 
ftps.execPROT("P");
ftps.login("user", "pass");
ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

It stucks in "234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation." tried with SSLContext, TrustManager allways the same ..

Comment: Just to be sure... did you try `ftps.connect(<actual_host_address_of_your_server>)`? (i.e.: using an InetAddress)

Comment: yes, and he get there OUTPUT 220-Microsoft FTP Service {message} 220--- Auth TLS 234 AUTH command ok. Expecting TLS Negotiation (get stucked here).

Comment: I found this [best solution](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/java-530-user-cannot-login-with-ftpsclient/) and it worked for me:


    `ftps.login(user, pwd);`  
    `ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` 
    `ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();`  
    `ftps.execPBSZ(0);// Set protection buffer size`  
    `ftps.execPROT("P");// Set data channel protection to private--`